# Is this sentence correct, or am I switching tenses incorrectly?

Tags: tenses

> As my health improved, I began to get involved in the local community—participating in committees, organizing projects, and networking with others to effect positive change.

Is it okay to switch tenses in the context? Also, am I using the correct punctuation to transition?

Comment: There are only two tensed verbs in the sentence (_improved_ and _began_), and both of them are past tense. All the other verbs are gerunds or infinitives, without any tense. What's the problem again?

Comment: Your hyphen followed by space does not work. Unspaced em dash or spaced en dash (“—” or “ – ”) would work—the former more American, the latter more British, I think—or you could use a comma or colon. Also probably “effect” rather than “affect” towards the end.

Comment: Did you *affect* change or did you *effect* change?

Comment: @JohnLawler Sorry for the confusion. I was thinking of the gerunds as verbs. I just wanted to know if using gerunds in a past tense sentence is grammatically correct. Thank you for your help.

Comment: @BrianDonovan Thank you! I changed it to effect. Do you happen to know if the unspaced em dash is more casual or formal than using a comma or colon?

Comment: Offhand I would say colon most formal, comma intermediate, dash least formal.

Answer (score 1):

In terms of everyday usage it's fine. If you think there is someone who might take you to task on your grammar, you might try replacing the dash with the work "by".

On a style note:

> "to effect positive change"

sounds a little like corporate speak and not very personal. How about:

> "...to help change people's lives for the better".

Comment: I agree that "to effect positive change" sounds a little like corporate speak, but I'm not sure that "to help change people's lives for the better" is much of an improvement.